# Can PubNub support messaging in groups AND tasks for all members?

Tags: android, server, pubnub

I have an idea for an android app, which will serve as  a group communication tool that allows people to actively communicate with group members, as well as assign tasks and allows for them to be checked as completed, all in the same location.

It's for a school project, so I am on a fairly strict time constraint, which is that it must be finished by January 3rd.

I have been looking for outside technologies that will allow me to both set up group messaging capabilities, as well as share tasks and their statuses between all devices in the group.

I am worried that this is a bit too ambitious for my time frame, even with a week off of school right before it is due, so I am prepared to limit the functionality to just the tasks and statuses if need be, considering I am still somewhat a noob with server data storage and retrieval.

My question to all of you more experienced users:

Is a technology, such as PubNub (found this on another post) capable of such tasks and group capabilities? Or am I looking for something else?

I'm still trying to get a feel for PubNub, and don't fully understand how it is used yet, which is why I want outside feedback before I go too far and get caught with my pants down.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Yes PubNub can be used for messaging in groups and tasks for all members.  There are a lot of great tutorials and samples to get you started on the PubNub Blog specifically for [building messaging / chat applications](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/tag/chat/).  Specifically there are a few for Android including  [4 Must-Have Tutorials For Building an Android Chat App](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-10-20-android-chat-app-roundup/) and [Easily Build an Android Chat App in One Afternoon](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-09-28-building-android-chat-app-in-an-afternoon/).  These should get you started.